# C# Correct way to change DateTime value?

Tags: c#

Is is possible to change the value returned by DateTime? Or at least assign it to a variable then change that variable?

```
 internal int hour;
    internal int minute;
    DateTime time = DateTime.Now;

public int incrementHour(int step)
        {
            if (step > 0 && hour < 24)
            {
                //step = step % hour;
                hour = (hour + step) % 24;
                time.AddHours(hour);
                return hour;
            }//end of if

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a positive number.");

                return 0;
            }//end of else
        }//end of incrementHour
```

Addhours doesn't really do anything from the looks of it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instances of `DateTime` are immutable - `AddHours()` returns a new instance of `DateTime` that reflects the changed value - so you have to re-assign the changed value to your time variable:

```
time =  time.AddHours(hour);
```

MSDN for [AddHours](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addhours.aspx) method (applies to all other methods of `DateTime` as well):

> This method does not change the value
>   of this DateTime. Instead, it returns
>   a new DateTime whose value is the
>   result of this operation. The Kind
>   property of the returned DateTime
>   object is the same as that of value.

Answer (score 3):

all you need to do is

```
time = time.AddHours(hour)
```

and that will be it

Answer (score 3):

See [documentation of DateTime.AddHours](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addhours.aspx), it does not change the parameter value but returns a new DateTime instance. Try:

```
time = time.AddHours(hour);
```